# ASP.NET working with DB-forms using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm learing ASP.NET. So here is the problem:

I have 2 tables in DB. One is "Customer" and the other is "Bill". Both have some attributes, but important thing is that "Bill" has FK "customer_id" that tells who the Bill belongs to. I have following code for create "Bill", generated by ASP.NET.

```
// GET: Bills/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {
            ViewBag.customer_id = new SelectList(db.Customers, "id_customer", "name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: racuns/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_bill,dv_bill,status,dv_paid,customer_id")] bill bill)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.bills.Add(bill);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.customer_id = new SelectList(db.customers, "id_customer", "name", bill.customer_id);
            return View(bill);
        }
```

This way I have form with fields to fulfill, and for FK customer_id I have dropdown menu to select one of existing Customers, which works fine.

In list of customers, I want to put by every Customer name a link which takes me to create bill form that same as previous one, but without dropdown menu, instead of that, customer_id should be sent by link, i managed to get that by this code.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add bill", "Create", "Bills", new { id = item.id_customer }, null)
```

Problem is, how do I use that ID in DB with all other information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want the user to be able to change the customer in this case I suggest adding a new `CreateForCustomer` action with a `customer_id` argument you can use to capture the customer_id from a link on your list. Then use that id to set the value of the Bill's customer_id. Here I've assumed your `customer_id` is a `Guid` but if it is something else like an `int` or `string` then change it to that.

In your controller:

```
// GET: Bills/CreateForCustomer
public ActionResult CreateForCustomer(Guid customer_id)
{
    // TODO: Verify that customer_id is valid and return HttpNotFound() if not.
    return View(new Bill { customer_id = customer_id });
}

// POST Bills/CreateForCustomer
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateForCustomer([Bind(Include = "id_bill,dv_bill,status,dv_paid,customer_id")] bill bill)
{
    // TODO: The usual POST stuff like validating and saving the entity.
}
```

In your CreateForCustomer.cshtml view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.customer_id)
// Instead of:
//@Html.DropDownList("customer_id")
```

In your customer list you can generate links like this:

```
// Note that I changed `id` to `customer_id` since that is what the CreateForCustomer action expects
@Html.ActionLink("Add bill", "CreateForCustomer", "Bills", new { customer_id = item.id_customer }, null)
```

There's a variety of ways to accomplish what you are after. I'm just trying to give you an idea of what MVC can do, and this solution seemed simpler and less confusing than adding a bunch of `if` statements to your existing Create action methods and View.

Comment: first of all, thx for editing my post, and for your answer. I my post I made mistake, now I edited that, I have been already added argument to create GET action, but i copyed old one. So basicly, all I have to do is to use ID as default value at dropdown list, I add it as you, but it dont make any changes. :(

Comment: Ok, Jeremy, thx once again, i get it, all i had to do is "hide" dropdown list?Right? :)

Comment: But how to hide it? If i delete it in form file, then i get error.

Comment: Well you have a couple options. Hiding the drop down list is one, although generally that is not the best thing to do and a <input type="hidden" ... /> element is used instead. I'll update the answer to show you what I might do in your situation.

Comment: Answer updated. If the user should never be able to change the customer_id from a drop down list, and the customer_id will always be provided to the action then CreateForCustomer I propose here could be renamed to Create.

Comment: Well, when i fulfill the form, and click "Create" i get this error, on pic u can also see how i did my action. I translated some "names" for my question, so ppl could easy understand what i'm doing...hope u will get my code :( http://prntscr.com/9ea7wc

Comment: Your controller action methods look good to me. That DbUpdateException is beyond the scope of this question. I suggest viewing the inner exception for more details, and researching it. I'm willing to bet that exception is addressed elsewhere on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97993/discussion-between-bruce-haset-lee-and-jeremy-cook).

Comment: Dude, once more, thx you again. I deleted old controller, made new one, made action like your, and it works in my test controller, now ill try to put it in original one, hope it will work. once more, ty :) you helped me a lot :)